# Reading old floppy disks / Fujitsu UF0002 Rev A USB drive?

Tags: floppy

Trying to pull some old data off of floppies, but having no luck.  I only have a couple of Windows 10 and a Mac OS X computer available at the moment.  I do have 2 of these Fujitsu UF0002 USB 3.5" floppy drives though.  Unfortunately when I plug them into the Mac nothing happens at all.  On the PCs it throws a warning about something being wrong with the hardware and they don't show up.  Should these work?  Trying to determine if I really have 2 bad drives on my hands or if I'm just missing a software piece.

Comment: At least on windows they should - any further details for the Windows error?

Comment: Hard to catch because it flashes by so fast.  Not seeing a way to get it back, but it's along the lines of "The last USB device connected has malfunctioned..."

Comment: Oh, "Device Descriptor Request Failed" does show up in device manager.  Probably just bad luck and 2 bad drives.

Comment: "Device Descriptor Request Failed" That sounds like a hardware error or something very low in the driver stack.  One thing to try is switching to a USB 2.0 port on your computer if you're currently using a USB 3.n gen1 (or worse, a 3.1 gen2) port.  In theory it shouldn't make a difference, in practice it often does.

Comment: https://tricksmaze.com/device-descriptor-request-failed/ http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/IndexDownload.asp?SoftwareGuid=FA24D399-CB1C-470D-9D18-1086D18D3C05

Comment: Sadly starting from this year Windows is loading wrong drivers from Windows Update by default for many custom USB devices/vendors (hard to say if by design or just because of wrongly assigned WHQL possibly also by design) !!! If the case You need to un-install the driver and install the right one **manually** but beware that after restart it might happen again there are utilities for workaround this like JUNGO WDREG or manulay deleting oem.inf entries ... Also use only USB 2.0 ports and back side ports as too long cables and front bypass cable often mess things up. Check BIOS USB settings

Comment: Try those usb floppy drives on a W7 machine if you have access, I use one on mine with no issues.

Answer (score 2):

"does not work" Errors are always a guesswork.

> Oh, "Device Descriptor Request Failed" does show up in device manager

Well, this can have many issues.

- Starting with a bad connector. A first step would be trying a different port of this PC, maybe it's the port (dirty etc.). Trying on a different PC also may help to diagnose.
- Since the device shows up in device manager, uninstalling it and searching again may resolve it.
- I wouldn't go so far an reinstall the USB driver - this has been a good way in XP, but no longer with W10.

For further analyze more information would be helpful. You may take a look into the device details and see if windows can at least get some basic information - like VID/PID.

- If it doesn't, then the very basic is screwed - as in port or controller damaged.
- if it does, it's more likely a driver error than a hardware one.

  I say more likely, as there are more weird faults than atoms in this universe - heck, I even once had a 6502 with a dead decimal flag :))

Oh, and then there are the USB suspension settings of Win10. While great in general, they can fail with older devices.

Comment: *I even once had a 6502 with a dead decimal flag.* You aren't alone with that.